# Javascript obtain outer parent id DIV

Tags: javascript, dom-events, parent-child

I have a structure that looks like the one below, I'm trying to get the id `foo`. It is the **only** `DIV` with id if we bubble up from the `onclick` `func()`, which means that there wont be other *DIVs* that contain an id inside `foo`. However, there can be other tags inside `foo` that contain an id (such as `bye, hello`).

No frameworks are being used.

```
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="foo">
    <p><p>
    <div class="bye">
        <input id="bye" type="text" value="test" />  
        <input id="hello" type="text" value="test" />
        <table>
            <tr><td onclick="func(event)">1</td></tr>
            <tr><td onclick="func(event)">2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly??

Comment: Trying to get the id `FOO` when I click on a table cell.

Comment: to quote: I'm trying to get the id foo.  Thats the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="foo">
    <p><p>
    <div class="bye">
        <input id="bye" type="text" value="test" />
        <input id="hello" type="text" value="test" />
        <table>
            <tr><td onclick="func(this)">1</td></tr>
            <tr><td onclick="func(this)">2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(elt) {
            // Traverse up until root hit or DIV with ID found
        while (elt && (elt.tagName != "DIV" || !elt.id))
            elt = elt.parentNode;
        if (elt) // Check we found a DIV with an ID
            alert(elt.id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
function findIdOfParent(obj) {
  var o = obj;
  while(!o.id) {
    o = o.parentNode;
  }

  alert(o.id); // 'foo'
}
```

The function `findIdOfParent` takes a DOM node. You could call it with `onclick="findIdOfParent(this);"`, but if you only want to pass `event`, as in your example, you'd have to extract the DOM node from `event.target` or whatever you're currently doing.

Comment: this must be the right answer, not the accepted answer which does not have any explanation

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parentNode property of the clicked element to iterate up through the DOM tree.

ie:

```
<td onclick="func(this)">
function func(item)
{
   var parent = item.parentNode;
   // and so on, or something similar
   var divId = div.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

elem is the  element that call the function on click

```
var found = false;
var myId = "";
while (elem &&!found) { 
    if (elem.id){
        found = true; 
        myId = elem.id;
    }
    elem = elem.parentNode; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you apply a simpler pattern? Instead of having onclick properties in your cells, attach a single click handler to your outermost div(s), then you just need to refer to `this`:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(event) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td") {
        alert(this.id);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fRxYB/

Or am I *completely* missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

To have a somewhat more generic version, I'd suggest this:

```
function func(event) {
    var par = findTop(event.target);
    console.log(par);
};

function findTop(node) {
    while(node.parentNode && node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'BODY') {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    return node;
}
```

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/37/