# how to know input field is belong to which section?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with differenct section ,and each section contain a different Input , each section has section id which is my primary key to update related data. 
 when user click on submit button i call javascript function "Set_Data()" to process my form data,at this function i need to know each field is belong to which section , 
would you please advise me what is the best soulution ?

```html
<form id="APIFORM">

    <div class="inner-wrap" id="SECTION1">
        <label>Your Full Name <input type="text" name="ABC" /></label>
        <label>Address <textarea name="GHI"></textarea></label>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-wrap" id="SECTION3">
        <label>DRAWERSTATUS <input type="text" name="JHK" /></label>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="inner-wrap" id="SECTION3">
        <label>Password <input type="password" name="OPL" /></label>
        <label>Password <input type="password" name="UTY" /></label>
    </div>

    <div class="button-section">
     <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" onclick="Set_Data();" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript obtain outer parent id DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658927/javascript-obtain-outer-parent-id-div)

Comment: @saeedyazdani I see one problem already, you have two divs with the same ID, this is a no-no in your html.

Comment: I'm guessing thats a typo as the OP has missed section2

Comment: What are you using section containers for in the html?  Just organization or something bigger?

Comment: Where's the JavaScript you tried?

Comment: Looks like he's only using the onclick rather than just allowing the form to be posted.

Comment: Section is Like primary KEY for me ,there is no java script yet ,please ignore syntax error since this code is only for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution
But i wondering to know if there is any solution which i can send key value with data value.some thing like :

```
<label>Password <input type="password" name="SECTION3[]UTY" /></label>
```

here is my solution :

```
function Set_Data();
{
    var mySection = document.getElementById('APIFORM');
    for (i = 1; i < mySection.length-1; i++) {
       var nodeKey = mySection[i].parentNode.parentNode.id;
    }
}
```